# How do I pull reflection out of this loop?

Tags: java, reflection

How do I pull the reflection out of this loop and pass in the getter method if that's possible.

```
public <E> void sortBy(final String fieldName, final boolean sortAsc, List<E> list){
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<E>() {
                public int compare(E o1, E o2) {
                    return compareFields(o1,o2,fieldName.replace("SortBy", "get"),sortAsc);
                }
            }
        );
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    protected <E> int compareFields(E o1, E o2,String fieldName, boolean sortAsc){
        try { 
            Comparable o1Data;
            Comparable o2Data;
            o1Data = (Comparable) o1.getClass().getMethod(fieldName).invoke(o1);
            o2Data = (Comparable) o2.getClass().getMethod(fieldName).invoke(o2);
            if(o1Data == null && o2Data == null){
                return 0;
            } else if (o1Data == null){
                return 1;
            } else if (o2Data == null){
                return -1;
            }
            int result = o2Data.compareTo(o1Data); 
            return (sortAsc) ? -result : result ; 
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

Context: I've got many screens with data tables. Each one is build from a List. Each data table needs to be sortable by each of its 6 columns. The columns are either Date or String.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can assume all the elements are the same type.

```
public <E> void sortBy(final String fieldName, final boolean sortAsc, List<E> list) throws NoSuchMethodException {
    final Method f = list.get(0).getClass().getMethod(fieldName.replace("SortBy", "get"));
    f.setAccessible(true);
    final int direction = sortAsc ? +1 : -1;
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<E>() {
        public int compare(E o1, E o2) {
            return compareFields(o1, o2, f, direction);
        }
    }
    );
}

@SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes", "unchecked"})
protected <E> int compareFields(E o1, E o2, Method getter, int sortAsc) {
    try {
        Comparable o1Data = (Comparable) getter.invoke(o1);
        Comparable o2Data = (Comparable) getter.invoke(o2);
        if (o1Data == null)
            return o2Data == null ? 0 : 1;
        if (o2Data == null)
            return -1;
        return sortAsc * o2Data.compareTo(o1Data);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have the data objects implement an interface that includes `getFieldByName` method.

Comment: +1, good idea. I would also add `getAvailableFields` to the interface to discover which fields are actually possible to access. The best thing is that you are actually avoiding reflection altogether.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the problem I see with this from a performance standpoint is that I can't pull that logic out of the sorting/compare loop.

Comment: If that becomes your bottleneck, you can have `getAccessorByName`, where `Accessor` has a method `getValue` that takes your object and returns the corresponding field. Then you can do the lookup and other preparations when you construct the accessor, taking into account the implementation of your data objects. I wouldn't trust reflection if performance is looked for, in my experiments it is slow, though in principle it could be implemented efficiently, so it could be faster in newer versions.

Answer (score 1):

The [Apache Bean Utils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/) are quite useful for this kind of thing. They most likely use reflection internally but it means you don't have to and you can have nice clean code:

```
...

Comparable o1Data = (Comparable) PropertyUtils.getProperty(o1, fieldName);
Comparable o2Data = (Comparable) PropertyUtils.getProperty(o2, fieldName);
if(o1Data == null && o2Data == null) {

...
```

Here, `fieldName` should be the name of the property/field, not the getter. Since the variable in your code holds the name of the getter you should probably call it something like `getterName` instead.